# can not remove item from a dropdownlist in datagrid c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagrid

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetCategorySubDivisionDesc()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    values.Add(0, "Please select");
    values.Add(1, "Whole Property Wanted");
    values.Add(2, "Flatshares & Rooms Wanted");
    values.Add(3, "Whole Properties Available To Rent");
    values.Add(4, "Flatshares & Rooms Available To Rent");
    values.Add(5, "Looking for Professional Space to Rent/Share");
    //values.Add(6, "Looking for Professional Space to Share");
    values.Add(7, "Looking for Professional Space to Buy");
    values.Add(8, "Practices Wanted to Buy");           
    return values;
}

Dictionary<int, string> CategorySubDivisionValues = Enums.GetCategorySubDivisionDesc();
```

I need a dropdown in datagrid with these values so I am binding it for each dropdown in _ItemDataBound event

```
DropDownList cboSpaceCategory = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("cboSpaceCategory");
            cboSpaceCategory.DataSource = CategorySubDivisionValues;
            cboSpaceCategory.DataTextField = "Value";
            cboSpaceCategory.DataValueField = "Key";
            cboSpaceCategory.DataBind();

 cboSpaceCategory.Items.Remove("Practices Wanted to Buy"); // not working
 cboSpaceCategory.Items.RemoveAt(int.Parse(cboSpaceCategory.Items.FindByText("Practices Wanted to Buy").Value)); // not working
```

This however does not remove the item. Please suggest any method to remove a item.

Comment: is that wpf or winforms or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing this.

```
ListItem itemToRemove = cboSpaceCategory.Items.FindByText("Practices Wanted to Buy");
cboSpaceCategory.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
```